# Getting multiple values from a single cell in .CSV file in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

How can I read multiple values from a single cell in CSV file in jmeter . I have an excel sheet as .csv input  and one of its column has mobile numbers which have 2 or more values.eg 
987@765@456 Which sampler should I use.

now I want it to split at @  as 987,765,456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the csv file in JMeter, use CSV data set config.

Check this [link](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) to understand how to use CSV data set config in JMeter.

Lets assume the column name is mobileNo which has the value as 987@765@456.

Use Beanshell preprocessor to replace '@' by ','.

```
mobileNo = vars.get("mobileNo");
mobileNo = mobileNo.replace("@", ",");
vars.put("mobileNo",mobileNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter's [__javaScript](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function to replace all occurences of `@` with `,` as follows:

Given that your `987@765@456` bit lives as `${mobileNumber}` JMeter Variable:

```
${__javaScript("${mobileNumber}".split('@').join('\,'),mobileNumber)}
```

The script above replaces all "at" signs with commas and stores the result in "mobileNumber" JMeter Variable.

To learn more about different JMeter Functions refer to [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series.